# What's the proper way to change a gconf schema during a .deb package upgrade?

Tags: installation, packaging, deb, gconf

I made some modifications to an open source package (Guake), and I had to change the type of some of the keys in the gconf schema.

The problem is that when I install the new .deb that I built, the keys set in gconf remain the old type, until they're unset, even though the new schema has been copied into place.

I assume the right fix is to make the installation process unset the keys, but this is my first time making a .deb and I haven't been able to figure out how to do that. Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking about defaults, then if the user has already set those keys, they won't change. The user's preferences take precedence.

Comment: I realize they won't change automatically, so I would like it to unset the keys as part of the installation process